# Applications from a different user folder appearing in Launchpad

Tags: applications, user-account, launchpad

I have an iMac with two different user accounts on it, each with their own Applications folder within the user folder, in addition of course to the system-wide Applications folder. I had a group of applications installed in the system Applications folder that I moved to user A's Applications folder, but they still appear in Launchpad for user B. Is there any way I can change this so that each user only sees their own applications and the system-wide applications? Thanks.